# Save number in Label even when restart app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to save the number I tapped on the button which is shown on the label. I want the number you tapped on the button to save in the label even when I close the app and add the additional tapps to the saved number.

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var TapLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Banner: ADBannerView!

    var taps = 0

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            Banner.hidden = true
            Banner.delegate = self
            self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        Banner.hidden = false
    }


    @IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton){

        taps += 1
        TapLabel.text = "Taps: \(taps)"


    }

}
```

Comment: Persist that number with `NSUserDefault`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefault` for this purpose like this:

To save an integer to a NSUserDefault you can use the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(textField.text, forKey: "key")
```

To get the value from the saved NSUserDefault use the following code:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("key")
```

**Edit**

To set the taps, do the following

```
@IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton){
    taps += 1
    TapLabel.text = "Taps: \(taps)"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(taps, forKey: "key")
}
```

To get the taps, just do this in your `viewDidLoad` function

```
TapLabel.text = String(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("key"))
```

Comment: How should i insert this code into my existing code?

Comment: There is an error in the viewDidLoad function in the line of textField.text

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But when I restart the app and start tapping on the button the score is set to 0 and counts up from there

Comment: Post your current code into your question as an update and I´ll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you need persistence for a small amount of data you can use NSUserDefaults.

This stores a key value pairing of data in a plist.

You can set and get the item using some key for your data.